# Calling SOAP Web Service from Java

Tags: java, soap

What is the best way to call a soap based web service and map the results to a Java objects?  The only thing I have is a wsdl url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use wsdl2java, you just supply the wsdl and it generates the client.

[Wsdl2java eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

Comment: @Kal Yes meant to say 2java, thank you for catching the typo.

Comment: Do I need to generate a local version of the wsdl file?  I just have a url to http://api2.corbis.com/WSCorbisOne/CorbisImage.asmx?WSDL

Comment: thanks Oscar.  I installed the plugin but it doesn't seem compatible with eclipse Helios when I launch the plugin.  Have you gotten it to work?  When I do import-->web reference I get below:

Comment: The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.apache.axis.wsdl2java.eclipse" was unable to instantiate class "org.apache.axis.wsdl2java.eclipse.wizards.WebReferenceImportWizard".
org/eclipse/core/internal/utils/Assert

Comment: I was able to get the http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/wsimport.html) and its reference implementation.

Given a WSDL, it can generate all the client artifacts for you using a tool called `wsimport`

Once you have the client packaged in a jar file, you can call the web service from a Java client.

Answer (score 0):

if you have wsdl then why are so late , dear create web service client import the wsdl into it , and the code will be created and Create object of servicelocator and then use service .